# Flutter how to convert Image data type to File data type?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Ok this is going to be my first question in this community.

I was working on a project which creates QrImage (qr_flutter) and converts it to Image.

So far it was OK, i can get Image from Qr data type.
But i need to upload this image to Firebase Storage.

In order to upload this **Image**, i need to convert it to **File** since the method **.putFile()** requires **File** data type as parameter.

Basically the thing i want to do looks like this:

```
Image image = QRtoImage();
File imageFile = ConvertImageToFile(image);
storage.upload(imageFile);
```

So i need a function `ConvertImageToFile(Image image)` here.

Also the usage of .putFile() looks like this:

```
UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child("xxx.jpg").putFile(imageFile);
```

How can i do this conversion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what's the data-type of `Image`?

Comment: Its a class actually.

Comment: could you provide more details on the source type?

Answer (score 0):

The [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package might be what you're looking for. It ables you to do this :

```
// Create an image
Image image = Image(320, 240);

// Save the image to disk as a PNG
File('test.png').writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(image));
```